# Minting NFT collection returns error: TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, nft, mint

I'm having trouble minting an NFT collection for testing purposes. I'm creating all the necessary account, creating the instructions and sending the transaction. Am I missing something? (I've tried on both localnet and devnet).

```
it('Mint NFT', async () => {
      const verifiedUser = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

      // 1. Airdrop 1 SOL to payer
      const signature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
          verifiedUser.publicKey,
          1000000000
      );
      const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
          {
              signature,
              ...latestBlockhash,
          },
          commitment
      );

      /**
       * Create an NFT collection on-chain, using the regular Metaplex standards
       * with the `payer` as the authority
       */
      async function createCollection(
          connection: Connection,
          payer: anchor.web3.Keypair,
          metadataV3: CreateMetadataAccountArgsV3
      ) {
          // create and initialize the SPL token mint
          console.log("Creating the collection's mint...");
          const mint = await createMint(
              connection,
              payer,
              // mint authority
              payer.publicKey,
              // freeze authority
              payer.publicKey,
              // decimals - use `0` for NFTs since they are non-fungible
              0
          );
          console.log('Mint address:', mint.toBase58());

          // create the token account
          console.log('Creating a token account...');
          const tokenAccount = await createAccount(
              connection,
              payer,
              mint,
              payer.publicKey,
              undefined,
              {
                  skipPreflight: true,
              }
          );
          console.log('Token account:', tokenAccount.toBase58());

          // mint 1 token ()
          console.log('Minting 1 token for the collection...');
          const mintSig = await mintTo(
              connection,
              payer,
              mint,
              tokenAccount,
              payer,
              // mint exactly 1 token
              1,
              // no `multiSigners`
              [],
              {
                  skipPreflight: true,
              },
              TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
          );
          // console.log(explorerURL({ txSignature: mintSig }));

          // derive the PDA for the metadata account
          const [metadataAccount, _bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
              [
                  Buffer.from('metadata', 'utf8'),
                  TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
                  mint.toBuffer(),
              ],
              TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
          );
          console.log('Metadata account:', metadataAccount.toBase58());

          // create an instruction to create the metadata account
          const createMetadataIx = createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
              {
                  metadata: metadataAccount,
                  mint: mint,
                  mintAuthority: payer.publicKey,
                  payer: payer.publicKey,
                  updateAuthority: payer.publicKey,
              },
              {
                  createMetadataAccountArgsV3: metadataV3,
              }
          );

          // derive the PDA for the metadata account
          const [masterEditionAccount, _bump2] =
              PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
                  [
                      Buffer.from('metadata', 'utf8'),
                      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
                      mint.toBuffer(),
                      Buffer.from('edition', 'utf8'),
                  ],
                  TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
              );
          console.log(
              'Master edition account:',
              masterEditionAccount.toBase58()
          );

          // create an instruction to create the metadata account
          const createMasterEditionIx =
              createCreateMasterEditionV3Instruction(
                  {
                      edition: masterEditionAccount,
                      mint: mint,
                      mintAuthority: payer.publicKey,
                      payer: payer.publicKey,
                      updateAuthority: payer.publicKey,
                      metadata: metadataAccount,
                  },
                  {
                      createMasterEditionArgs: {
                          maxSupply: 0,
                      },
                  }
              );

          // create the collection size instruction
          const collectionSizeIX = createSetCollectionSizeInstruction(
              {
                  collectionMetadata: metadataAccount,
                  collectionAuthority: payer.publicKey,
                  collectionMint: mint,
              },
              {
                  setCollectionSizeArgs: { size: 1 },
              }
          )

          try {
              // construct the transaction with our instructions, making the `payer` the `feePayer`
              const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction()
                  .add(createMetadataIx)
                  .add(createMasterEditionIx)
                  .add(collectionSizeIX);
              tx.feePayer = payer.publicKey
              tx.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")).blockhash;

              // send the transaction to the cluster
              const txSignature = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
                  connection,
                  tx,
                  [payer],
                  {
                      skipPreflight: true,
                  }
              );

              console.log('\nCollection successfully created!');
          } catch (err) {
              console.error('\nFailed to create collection:', err);

              throw err;
          }

          // return all the accounts
          return {
              mint,
              tokenAccount,
              metadataAccount,
              masterEditionAccount,
          };
      }

      const metadataV3 = {
          data: {
              name: 'string',
              symbol: 'string',
              uri: 'string',
              sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
              creators: null,
              collection: {
                  verified: true,
                  key: new PublicKey(
                      'F17gXajNLmVdMXtCPVpJ8enhwoxtscmDf7fLoJE8vUgw'
                  ),
              },
              uses: null,
          },
          isMutable: true,
          collectionDetails: null,
      };

      const { mint, tokenAccount, metadataAccount } = await createCollection(
          connection,
          verifiedUser,
          metadataV3
      );

     
  });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.